# Showing reminders in native calender in proper format(minute or day or week or year)

Tags: android, calendar

I want to add three different type reminder for a single event.

*Example: For a event I want to add a reminder 1 week before the event deadline and another two reminders 1 day and 1 hour before respectively.*

I managed to set the reminders for a single event, but I am facing a problem in setting proper time format in reminder menu.

The reminder time shows when the particular event is pressed from the native calender it shows two consecutive 4 or 5  digit no. in the reminder list., not in the proper day or week format.

To add a reminder I am Using Reminder.MINUTES .

Is it possible to add a reminder in day or week format except minute format?

Answer (score 0):

Try with this

```
DateFormat dateFormat = dateFormat.format(new Date(yourTime));
```

Comment: I want to show the reminder time in proper format like days or weeks or hours. ex: like 2 days or 3 weeks or 5 hours